# Bind Control depending bool

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have to accomplish the following task and don't know how to do it at all.

I am using a WizardControl (XCeed Wpf Toolkit) and want to skip one page, depending on a certain state in the ViewModel (let's say a bool-variable).
To achieve this I have to bind a different Control (a WizardPage) to the previous WizardPage's NextPage DependencyProperty according to this bool-variable. I think this can be done somehow with DataTrigger, but I am not so experienced in this topic. Can someone please help me?

The minimal code sample ist:

```
<xctk:Wizard>
  <xctkWizardPage x:Name="Page1" NextPage="Page2"/>
  <xctkWizardPage x:Name="Page2"/>
  <xctkWizardPage x:Name="Page3"/>
  </xctkWizardPage>
</xctk:Wizard>
```

```
public bool Property { get; set; }
```

What I want to do is make the "NextPage" of "Page1" dependant on the "Property", e.g. have "Page2" as NextPage if Property == true, otherwise go to "Page3".

Thank you very much for your help!

Jan

Comment: I normally do not recommend doing things in the code if it can be done in XAML but in your case, you should do that! 
Create an observable collection containing the Pages and use their indices to navigate

Comment: It is possible to bind a custom method to the NextPage command. You could create a method that checks if the boolean is set and return the page you want.
See [wizard class](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Wizard.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
<xctk:Wizard>
  <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page1">
    <Style TargetType="xctk:WizardPage">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Property}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="NextPage" Value="{Binding ElementName=Page2}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Property}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="NextPage" Value="{Binding ElementName=Page3}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </xctk:WizardPage>

  <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page2"/>
  <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page3"/>
</xctk:Wizard>
```

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: This won't work with `NextPage="Page2"` directly set at Page1. Besides that it's not a Binding, the directly set value (a so-called local value) has higher [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) than the value set by the Setters in the DataTriggers.

Comment: @Clemens you are absolutely right. I just made a mistake while transforming my code to the minimal example. Corrected it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
<Style TargetType="xctWizardPage">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Property="YourProperty" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="NextPage" Value="Page2" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Property="YourProperty" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="NextPage" Value="Page3" />
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Try something like this.